# Google Cloud NL entity recognizer grouping words together

Tags: python, nlp, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-nl

When attempting to find the entities in a long input of text, Google Cloud's natural language program is grouping together words and then getting their incorrect entity. Here is my program:

```
def entity_recognizer(nouns):

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/superaitor/Downloads/link"
text = ""
for words in nouns:
    text += words + " "
client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
    text = text.decode('utf-8')

document = types.Document(
    content=text.encode('utf-8'),
    type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

encoding = enums.EncodingType.UTF32
if sys.maxunicode == 65535:
    encoding = enums.EncodingType.UTF16


entity = client.analyze_entities(document, encoding).entities
entity_type = ('UNKNOWN', 'PERSON', 'LOCATION', 'ORGANIZATION',
               'EVENT', 'WORK_OF_ART', 'CONSUMER_GOOD', 'OTHER')

for entity in entity:
    #if entity_type[entity.type] is "PERSON":
    print(entity_type[entity.type])
    print(entity.name)
```

Here nouns is a list of words. I then turn that into a string(i've tried multiple ways of doing so, all give the same result), but yet the program spits out output like:

```
PERSON
liberty secularism etching domain professor lecturer tutor royalty 
government adviser commissioner
OTHER
business view society economy
OTHER
business
OTHER
verge industrialization market system custom shift rationality
OTHER
family kingdom life drunkenness college student appearance income family 
brink poverty life writer variety attitude capitalism age process 
production factory system
```

Any input on how to fix this?

Comment: I do not really understand what "input" are you giving to your code and how are you passing it. Could you add an example? I am providing an answer anyway, just in case I guessed it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [analyze entities in a text](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-entities#analyzing_entities_in_a_string) you can use a sample from the documentation which looks something like this:

```
import argparse
import sys

from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types
import six

def entities_text(text):
    """Detects entities in the text."""
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

    if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
        text = text.decode('utf-8')

    # Instantiates a plain text document.
    document = types.Document(
        content=text,
        type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

    # Detects entities in the document. You can also analyze HTML with:
    #   document.type == enums.Document.Type.HTML
    entities = client.analyze_entities(document).entities

    # entity types from enums.Entity.Type
    entity_type = ('UNKNOWN', 'PERSON', 'LOCATION', 'ORGANIZATION',
                   'EVENT', 'WORK_OF_ART', 'CONSUMER_GOOD', 'OTHER')

    for entity in entities:
        print('=' * 20)
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('name', entity.name))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('type', entity_type[entity.type]))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('metadata', entity.metadata))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('salience', entity.salience))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('wikipedia_url',
              entity.metadata.get('wikipedia_url', '-')))

entities_text("Donald Trump is president of United States of America")
```

The output of this sample is:

```
====================
name            : Donald Trump
type            : PERSON
metadata        : <google.protobuf.pyext._message.ScalarMapContainer object at 0x7fd9d0125170>
salience        : 0.9564903974533081
wikipedia_url   : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump
====================
name            : United States of America
type            : LOCATION
metadata        : <google.protobuf.pyext._message.ScalarMapContainer object at 0x7fd9d01252b0>
salience        : 0.04350961744785309
wikipedia_url   : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States
```

As you can see in this example, Entity Analysis inspects the given text for known entities (proper nouns such as public figures, landmarks, etc.). It's not gonna provide you entity for each word in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of classifying according to entities, I would use Google default categories directly, changing

```
entity = client.analyze_entities(document, encoding).entities
```

to

```
categories = client.classify_text(document).categories
```

and consequently up-dating the code. I wrote the following sample code based on [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/classifying-text#classifying_content_1), further developed [in github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/language/cloud-client/v1).

```
def run_quickstart():
    # [START language_quickstart]
    # Imports the Google Cloud client library
    # [START migration_import]
    from google.cloud import language
    from google.cloud.language import enums
    from google.cloud.language import types
    # [END migration_import]

    # Instantiates a client
    # [START migration_client]
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
    # [END migration_client]

    # The text to analyze
    text = u'For its part, India has said it will raise taxes on 29 products imported from the US - including some agricultural goods, steel and iron products - in retaliation for the wide-ranging US tariffs.'
    document = types.Document(
        content=text,
        type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

    # Detects the sentiment of the text
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment

    # Classify content categories
    categories = client.classify_text(document).categories

    # User category feedback
    for category in categories:
        print(u'=' * 20) 
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('name', category.name))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('confidence', category.confidence))

    # User sentiment feedback
    print('Text: {}'.format(text))
    print('Sentiment: {}, {}'.format(sentiment.score, sentiment.magnitude))
    # [END language_quickstart]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_quickstart()
```

Does this solution works for you? If not, why?

Comment: While this works very well at finding the overall sentiment of the text, it doesn't find the entity of each individual word in the text. For example, if "Adam" was passed, the entity recognizer should recognize that as a PERSON. However, it seems to be grouping lots of words together instead of individually assigning sentiments. Sorry, should have been a bit more clear on that. My input, by the way, is first a list of words, and is then converted into a full string (Which is what you guessed).